# Sharepoint site does not show up in hub site list

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I am creating sites for new projects and am adding them to a hub site that shows all active projects. I am adding my users as members to that site. Neither me or my users are able to see these new sites in the Hub site's site list. It seems as though the sites are not a member of the Hub site, but the SharePoint admin center says they are. How do I get this Hub's sub-sites to list correctly? My end goal is to have any sites added to the hub site show up in the site list on the hub site.

Edit: i have added a screenshot of the list of sites I can explicitly add to the Site List web part for the Hub Site's homepage.

Hub site homepage:
[image: hub site homepage]

Sharepoint admin list:
[image: sharepoint admin list]

Site list web part associated sites list:
[image]

Comment: Are you using SharePoint default "Sites" web part? How much time you waited after associating sites with hub site? All associated sites are using permissions of hub site or separate permissions?

Comment: I am using the default Sites web part, these sites were created 3 days ago. I have not changed anything with permissions on these new sites. My users were added to each site's group as members.

Comment: Can you try selecting "All sites in the hub" option?

Comment: "All sites in the hub" is the setting I am attempting to get working right now. I only selected "Select sites" to show that there are no additional sites associated with the hub to choose from, only the Hub itself.

Comment: I would also like to mention that the project sites I have added to the Hub site do show the hub navigation menu at the top of the window but it only lists the hub site itself

Comment: I don't know what is going on but I had the hub site's homepage sitting on my monitor and out of the corner of my eye I saw the sub-sites populate on the site list, when I went to that window to take a look at the site list they all disappeared again. I had made no changes to cause this.

Comment: Try clearing browser cache/cookies (for all time) once and see if it works. Also check if there are any errors in browser console when you refresh the page.

Comment: I have done those, still nothing. Oddly enough, one of the sites i was testing with and had showing up in the site list without issue was deleted once I was finished testing, I reinstated it yesterday to see if it would return to the site list and it has not.